# Calling a function in a different class without creating a new instance of the class

Tags: java, class, oop

I have the following classes: Main which creates an instance of Game which creates an instance of Player and an instance of World, World creates an instance of Floor.

Now I want to call a method in Floor from Player, which is basically just a getter at this point, but may develop more complexity later. What would be the best way to go about this? Creating a method in Game that calls Floor and then writes to player? I feel like creating a new instance of Floor in Player wouldn't be wise. (But don't actually know.) And I assume that there is no way to directly step up in my hierarchy to call game.world.floor from Player?

Comment: Is there only ever one `Floor` in the application?  If so, you'll want to look into something called the Singleton Pattern.  Can there be more than one instance of `Floor` and the `Player` just needs to know which one he is using?  If so, then you'll need to pass a reference to `Floor` to the `Player`.  If the `Player` must _always_ have such a reference, it should be required in the constructor.

Comment: There's really more to it than just using the mechanics of the language to allow you to call a method or not.  The natural real-world relationships between the objects in question is important to understand.  Does this method even *belong* on `Floor`?  What does this method do?  What items in the state of the application does it use, and what does it change?

Comment: There's only one floor, so I'll look into the Singleton Pattern, thank you. And David, I'm not sure, as I was saying I believe maybe the method should go on Game, but it uses values that Floor sets, and Player uses them, currently it's as simple as that.

Comment: Look into something called the Law Of Demeter as well.  Are the `Player` and the `Floor` directly interacting with one another, or are they indirectly affecting one another by interacting with something else?  (Such as the `Game`.)  If they directly interact with one another, they are immediate neighbors and should have either a uni-directional (such as a `Floor` having a collection of `Player`s or a `Player` having a reference to `Floor`) or bi-directional (both, though one should still be the "owner" of the reference) reference to one another.  As you can see, there's much to think about :)

Comment: @David I don't think it's necessarily a good idea to suggest using the Singleton pattern in cases like these.

Comment: Depending on the Singleton pattern builds in the assumption that there is only one Floor in the World. The Player presumably has some notion of location. Maybe part of its location is the relevant Floor object?

Comment: @sdasdadas: It might be, we can't really know with the information provided.  But if there should only ever be one `Floor` then it might make sense to have a static factory for the `Floor` which would maintain that single instance.  We don't even really know what a `Floor` is based on the description.

Comment: @David But without knowing you're offering a suggestion that's very restrictive by nature. It's more likely the OP may decide that he needs more than one floor (levels?) or more than one world (space travel!). It's far easier to use a getter.

Comment: David has left me lots to think about, I'll tinker around a bit, thank you for the help.

Comment: @sdasdadas: You could be right, which is why I offered as a comment instead of an answer.  If we're not talking about a single instance and instead a more complex object relationship, then perhaps my other suggestions are helpful.  The objects can carry references to one another, or instead of interacting with one another at all would instead interact with the `Game`, which mediates those interactions.

Comment: @David I can agree with that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Player knows about World.

World knows about Floor.

To allow Player to access floor, do the following:

Implement this:

```
class World
{
    private Floor floor;

    public Floor getFloor()
    {
        return floor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use make the Floor Singleton like this

```
public class Floor{
    private static Floor instance;
    private Floor(){
        // do initial things
    }
    public static Floor getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Floor();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now you can access Floor instance from any where by calling

```
Floor.getInstance()
```

It will always use a single instance of Floor no matter from where you are calling